# Fetching JSON onClick in jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

```
<script>
        var twitchApi = "https://api.twitch.tv/kraken/streams";
        $.getJSON(twitchApi, function (json) {
        for (var i = 0; i < 9; i++) {
        var streamGame = json.streams[i].game;
        var streamThumb = json.streams[i].preview.medium;
        var streamVideo = json.streams[i].channel.name;
        <!-- var streamViewers = json.streams[i].streamViewers; -->
        $('#twitch').append('<img style="width: 250px; height: 250px;" src="' + streamThumb + '"></img>'); 
    }
});
</script>
```

So I've got this code. And I want to make it that onClick on an image or button it fetches 9 more stream previews. How can I do that? Could someone fix the code for me?
Also, how can I edit the Thumbnails which are getting fetched from the JSON?

Comment: bind the click event of element like `$(function(){    $('#yourbuttonid').click(function(){  
 // Your above code 
  }); 
});`

Comment: @Satpal Like this? http://pastebin.com/fw1pCzDM If yes, it doesn't work.. I want the page to display the 9 thumbnails as soon as you open it and then if you want you can click the button to load 9 more.

Answer (score 0):

You can get the data and persist in a variable, then display on demand.

```
$(function() {
    //varianles
    var i=0;
    var twitchApi = "https://api.twitch.tv/kraken/streams";
    var twitchData;
    //Get data from API and store it in variable
    $.getJSON(twitchApi, function(json) {
        twitchData = json.streams;

        //Set upon page load
        setData()
    });

    function setData(){
        var j = twitchData.length > (i + 9)  ? (i + 9) : twitchData.length;
        for (; i < j; i++) {
            var streamGame = twitchData[i].game;
            var streamThumb = twitchData[i].preview.medium;
            var streamVideo = twitchData[i].channel.name;
            <!-- var streamViewers = twitchData[i].streamViewers; -->
            $('#twitch').append('<img style="width: 250px; height: 250px;" src="' + streamThumb + '"></img>');
        }
    }       

    //Bind click handlers
    $('#button').click(function() {
        setData();
    }); 
});
```